# Sandbox Error: All Queries Getting Error HTTP CODE[0]

Tags: apex, error, sandbox, developer-console, spring-20

yesterday the sandox in which I was working was refreshed and after that all the queries I make throught the Anonimous Window are getting this error. The message says:

Line: undefined, Column: undefined
Response to EXEC was : . HTTP CODE[0]

[image: HTTP 0 error]

I've searched in many questions here and in the Trailblazer community but couldn't find nothing similar to this.

I tried to open the log and inspect but no log is written when this happens. Also I've been reading about the HTTP 0 status and apparently that status doesn't exist, and which it indicates is apparently a problem connecting with the server, but there's no 0 status in an HTTP request, and I'm not making really a request, I'm only executing one simple query in apex like **List theList = [select Id from Account]**. Even that simple query returns the error, so I think that this is not related to my code itself.

I've tried resetting my connection settings (doing ipconfig release or flushdns commands, or going to the control panel on windows) but it didn't work.

In other sandbox that I have this doesn't occur, but this sandbox is in version Summer 20 and the one in which I've got the problem is in Spring 20

**Note:** I've been integrating several changes from my colleagues into my sandbox, and some of them are using not the Spring 20 but the Summer 20 version. Could this be related with the issue?

Thanks very much for reading all of this and for your time, any help would be very appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried closing the developer console, re-logging into the sandbox, and then re-opening the developer console? If you can't run any script (even something as simple as `System.debug()`), I'd assume it's some sort of connection issue.

Comment: Helo @Kris Goncalves thankyou for your help, yes I've tried to logout and loggin again, and I've also tried it in other browser like firefox. I've also moved some adjustments in control panel (in windows) but it seems that I can access normally any other site or other sandboxes but the problem is only with this one. I suspect it has something to do with deploying metadata between versions Summer 20 and Spring 20, I think somehow it damaged the sandbox.